# How to define a type alias with generic in swift

Tags: swift, generics, type-alias

I am working on predicates transformer functions in swift:

```
infix operator ⋀ {}
infix operator ∨ {}
prefix operator ¬ {}
infix operator ⟹ {}


func ⋀ <T>(A : T->Bool , B: T->Bool)->T->Bool{
    return { x in A(x) && B(x)}
}

func ∨ <T>(A : T->Bool , B: T->Bool)->T->Bool{
    return { x in A(x) || B(x)}
}

prefix func ¬ <T>(A : T->Bool)->T->Bool{
    return { x in !A(x)}
}


func ⟹ <T>(A : T->Bool , B: T->Bool)->T->Bool{
    return { x in (¬A ∨ B)(x)}
}

func TRUE<T>()->T->Bool{
    return{x in true}
}

func FALSE<T>()->T->Bool{
    return{x in false}
}

infix operator ∘ {}
func ∘ <X,Y,Z>(f:X->Y, g:Y->Z)->X->Z{
    return{ x in g(f(x))}
}

func PTRANS<X,Y> (f:X->Y)->(Y->Bool)->(X->Bool){
    return {q in (f ∘ q) }
}
```

I tried to define a typealias for predicates type : `PRED<T> = X->Bool` where `X` in a generic type, so that my code could be rewrite e.g. like 
:

```
func PTRANS<X,Y> (f:X->Y)->PRED<Y>->PRED<X>{
    return {q in (f ∘ q) }
}
```

I've tried :

```
typealias PRED = <T>(T->Bool)
```

but I get the following error message :

> *Only syntactic type can be generic*

Trying : `typealias PRED<T> = (T->Bool)` seems syntactically incorrect leading to:

> expected = in typealiase declaration

How could I declare a `typealias` similarly to `Array<T>` for predicate on `T` :
`typealias PRED<T> = T->Bool` ?

any ideas?

Comment: You can't do this.  This is also probably a duplicate.  I feel like this has been asked before.

Comment: @Claude Nice Sugar. Do you have these on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least at the moment, `typealias` doesn't support generic type alias, like the C++ `using` keyword.

But you can do it in the following way.

```
struct Pred<A> {
    typealias t = A -> Bool
}
let gt2: Pred<Int>.t = { n in n > 2 }
```